# Rust recursion (how can i speed it up?)

Tags: recursion, optimization, rust

I`m learning rust and i have this piece of code here:

```rust
fn f(n: i64) -> i64 {
    if n == 0 {
        return 1;
    }
    if n > 0 {
        return 2 * f(1 - n) + 3 * f(n - 1) + 2;
    }
    -1 * f(-1 * n)
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", f(50))
}
```

It seems to work very slow. I left it running for some time with no result in ~2 hours.

I figured out that there is alot of calculations of f() function with the same arguments.
In python the easy way to solve the problem is to use cache:

```py
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache
def f(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    return 2 * f(1 - n) + 3 * f(n - 1) + 2 if n > 0 else -1 * f(-n)

res = 0

for s in str(f(50)):
    res += int(s)

print(res)
```

Is there any way to make it right in rust?

Comment: Use [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) and cache the results of previous invocations.

Comment: As @caTS suggests, the best way is to implement `f` using dynamic programming. If, however, you want something quick and dirty like Python's `functools.lru_cache` decorator, there are [crates implementing similar macros](https://docs.rs/lru-cache-macros/latest/lru_cache_macros/) out there.

Comment: Generally, caching the result of a function call based on the parameters is called memoization. There are a few crates available that provide attribute macros for this, includind [michie](https://lib.rs/crates/michie), [cached](https://lib.rs/crates/cached), and [memoize](https://lib.rs/crates/memoize)

Comment: You know you can write this function as `if n < 0 { -5 + 2*n } else if n > 0 { 5 + 2*n } else { 1 }`, right?

Comment: Also, as for all performance-related questions, you are compiling in release mode, right?

Comment: @Jmb Thx. Yes, I learned that rust is much slower without the --release flag. Your solution looks very effective, but I'm not sure how you came to it. What is it or where can I read about it?

Comment: @Wilper first notice that for `n>1`, we have `1-n < 0`, so `f(1-n) = -f(n-1)`. Therefore for `n>1` we have `f(n) = -2*f(n-1) + 3*f(n-1) + 2 = f(n-1) + 2`, which is a simple [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression): `f(n) = f(1) + 2*(n-1)`. Then compute by hand the special cases `f(0)` and `f(1)` and you get to my solution.